# Custom React hook receiving typescript error on useReducer state value

Tags: typescript, react-hooks

I'm trying to write a fetch helper hook in typescript. I am getting a typescript error noted in the code below that I do not understand how to fix.

```
import * as React from 'react';

const INITIAL_STATE = {data: undefined, loading: false, error: undefined};
const ACTIONS = {
  LOADING: 'LOADING',
  ERROR: 'ERROR',
  DONE: 'DONE',
};
interface UseApiFetch<DataType> {
  data?: DataType;
  error: any;
  loading: boolean;
}
interface Action<DataType> {
  type: string;
  error?: any;
  data?: DataType;
}
const reducer = <DataType>(
  state: UseApiFetch<DataType>,
  {type, error, data}: Action<DataType>
): UseApiFetch<DataType> => {
  switch (type) {
    case ACTIONS.LOADING:
      return {...INITIAL_STATE, loading: true};
    case ACTIONS.ERROR:
      return {...INITIAL_STATE, error};
    case ACTIONS.DONE:
      return {...INITIAL_STATE, data};
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

const useApiFetch = <DataType>(
  fetcher: (...args: any[]) => Promise<any>,
  ...params: any[]
): UseApiFetch<DataType> => {
  const [state, dispatch] = React.useReducer(reducer, INITIAL_STATE);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (fetcher) {
      dispatch({type: ACTIONS.LOADING});
      fetcher(...params)
        .then((data) => dispatch({type: ACTIONS.DONE, data}))
        .catch((error) => dispatch({type: ACTIONS.ERROR, error}));
    }
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, [fetcher, ...params]);
  /*
   Error occurs here:
   Type 'UseApiFetch<unknown>' is not assignable to type 'UseApiFetch<DataType>'.
     Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'DataType'.
      'DataType' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'unknown'.
  */
  return state;
};

export default useApiFetch;

// in another file I call it like this
function myFetcherFunction(
  userId: number
): Promise<MyFetcherReturnType> {
  return client.api('myRequest', userId);
}
const {data, error, loading} = useApiFetch<MyFetcherReturnType>(myFetcherFunction, userId);
```

Comment: Tyr to add a type to `useReducer`: `const [state, dispatch] = React.useReducer<UseApiFetch<DataType>>(reducer, INITIAL_STATE);`

Comment: @Anton Thank you for your help. That gives me this error: `interface UseApiFetch<DataType>
Type 'UseApiFetch<DataType>' does not satisfy the constraint 'Reducer<any, any>'.
  Type 'UseApiFetch<DataType>' provides no match for the signature '(prevState: any, action: any): any'.ts(2344)`. And my dispatches are getting this error: `Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.ts(2322)`

Comment: I was mistaken about the typing of useReducer. I added an answer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need to add a type to the `useReducer`.

```
const [state, dispatch] = React.useReducer<
    (
      state: UseApiFetch<DataType>,
      action: Action<DataType>
    ) => UseApiFetch<DataType>
  >(reducer, INITIAL_STATE)
```

The type parameter defines the type of the reducer function. Without this type TypeScript will try to infer the type from the reducer, but since the reducer is a generic function TypeScript (or possibly React) infers the type of the state as `UseApiFetch<unknown>`, since it can't type a value with a generic type `UseApiFetch<T>`.

Ideally you would be able to reuse the existing type of the reducer here (something like `typeof reducer<DataType>`), but I haven't found a way to achieve that.